# Adapting the grey values from ggpot2 scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greys")

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a plot with the data and code below. I would like to change the grey values used for the bars, to make them both one step darker. I do however not see anything in `?scale_fill_brewer`, that would allow me to do this. Is there an easy solution to fix this?

Data:

```
counts_truth  <- structure(list(x_label = c("Truth ECOST = 0.52", "Truth ECOST = 0.39", 
"Truth ECOST = 0.26", "Truth ECOST = 0.13", "Truth ECOST = 0.00", 
"Truth ECOST = 0.52", "Truth ECOST = 0.39", "Truth ECOST = 0.26", 
"Truth ECOST = 0.13", "Truth ECOST = 0.00"), treatment = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("control", "treatment"
), class = "factor", scores = structure(c(control = 0.424793388429752, 
treatment = 0.498594189315839), .Dim = 2L, .Dimnames = list(c("control", 
"treatment")))), percentage = c(0.163636363636364, 0.272727272727273, 
0.427272727272727, 0.6, 0.781818181818182, 0.319587628865979, 
0.360824742268041, 0.474226804123711, 0.701030927835051, 0.88659793814433
), remove = c("Truth ECOST ", "Truth ECOST ", "Truth ECOST ", 
"Truth ECOST ", "Truth ECOST ", "Truth ECOST ", "Truth ECOST ", 
"Truth ECOST ", "Truth ECOST ", "Truth ECOST "), ECOST = c("0.52", 
"0.39", "0.26", "0.13", "0.00", "0.52", "0.39", "0.26", "0.13", 
"0.00")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))

library(ggplot2)
counts_truth %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = ECOST, y = percentage, fill = treatment, label=sprintf("%0.2f", round(percentage, digits = 2)))) + 
geom_col(position = 'dodge') + 
geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),    # move to center of bars
          vjust = -0.5,    # nudge above top of bar
          size = 5) +           
scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greys") + 
theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick solution would be to use `scale_fill_grey` to adjust the continuum of greys to be slightly darker. Based on your dataset, the below will darken the plot.

Adjust `start` and `end` parameters as needed. They range between 0 (black) and 1 (white).

```
counts_truth %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = ECOST, y = percentage, fill = treatment, label=sprintf("%0.2f", round(percentage, digits = 2)))) + 
    geom_col(position = 'dodge') + 
    geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),    # move to center of bars
              vjust = -0.5,    # nudge above top of bar
              size = 5) +           
    scale_fill_grey(start = 0.8, end = 0.5) +
    theme_bw()
```

Comment: I'll take it! Thank you very much